# Receiving "Status 401" Error When Sending Metadata to Backend from Stripe Webhook in Next.js

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, cloud, webhooks

I'm developing a Next.js application with Stripe for payment processing and have encountered an issue with my Stripe webhook implementation. Specifically, I'm handling **`checkout.session.completed`** events to process checkout sessions and forward metadata to my backend. This setup works perfectly in my local environment, but when deployed to the cloud, I receive a "Status 401" error upon sending the POST request with metadata to my backend.

Here's the relevant portion of my webhook function:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const secret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
const stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY;

const stripe = new Stripe(stripeSecretKey as string, {
  apiVersion: "2023-08-16",
});

async function handleCheckoutSession(session: any) {
  // Attempting to retrieve the session and send metadata to the backend
}

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // Code to handle POST request and verify Stripe signature
}

Upon receiving a checkout.session.completed event, I try to retrieve the session and send metadata to my backend using fetch(). However, I'm faced with a Status 401 error, indicating unauthorized access, despite the fact that this error does not occur during local testing.

Here's the error screenshot for reference:
enter image description here
```

I have double-checked my environment variable setup and the code structure but cannot pinpoint the issue. Could someone provide insights into what might be causing this discrepancy between local and cloud environments or suggest a resolution for this **`Status 401`** error?

**What I've Tried:**

1. **Verified Environment Variables:** I double-checked all my environment variables (**`STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET`**, **`STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`**) to ensure they are correctly set in both my local and cloud environments.
2. **Local vs. Cloud Testing:** I confirmed that the webhook and metadata forwarding function correctly in my local development environment, receiving successful responses from my backend.
3. **Authorization Headers:** I reviewed the request headers to make sure the correct authorization tokens were being sent in the cloud environment as they are in the local environment.
4. **Error Logs:** I checked both Stripe's and my cloud provider's logs for any additional error messages or clues that could point to the cause of the **`Status 401`** error.

**What I Was Expecting:**

Given that the webhook works as expected locally, I anticipated the same behavior in the cloud environment: that the webhook would successfully receive **`checkout.session.completed`** events from Stripe, retrieve the session details, and send the required metadata to my backend without encountering authorization issues. The **`Status 401`** error suggests an authentication problem, which is puzzling given the consistency of my environment variables and request headers across environments.

Comment: Can you share the exact line of code that is returning a 404 error? Also can you share the full error message?

Comment: Now that I see the vercel logs, when I make the test payment in stripe, the call to the webhook does not appear within the stripe logs, it directly appears within the stripe dashboard 401, by chance, I did not configure the next cors. js, could that be the cause?